# Putting HTML, CSS and Node.js/Ruby together with Heroku, Git and AWS

Tags: ruby, html, node.js, heroku, amazon-web-services

I've been trying to use AWS with Git and Heroku to deploy a web app.

I'm able to take their *"Hello World"* example and deploy it.

Where do you need to have your HTML/CSS files plugged into in order to deploy those as well?

If there's a guide out there or anything you can point me to that'd be great.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to serve static HTML/CSS files, you can put these in a ./public or ./static directory in your app, then add app.use calls in your node.js server script. For example:

`app.use('/public',express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

Which is telling the server to return content from `yourappurl/public` if it gets a `/public` request.